# DAX Code that pulls out values when they differentiate between columns

Tags: duplicates, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to to pull out rows that have a duplicate value in one column but different value in another column

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTFO5.png)

So when I load this dataset into PowerBI, I want to to pull out IDs 1 and 3, and pull out the two programs that their two programs (1:Grocery/Supermarket, 3:Retail/Supermarket).

Currently my DAX code looks like

```
dupecounter = CALCULATE(
             COUNTA('Data'[ID]),
             FILTER('Data', 'Data'[Program] <> EARLIER('Data'[Program])
       ))
```

But its not quite doing what I need it to do

Answer (score 0):

I don't tested this, but this should create a new table, where we leave only ID with more than one program. (put this syntax in New Table)

```
NewTable:
FILTER(
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Data'[ID],
    "CountOfPrograms", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( values('Data'[Program]) ) )
)
,[CountOfPrograms] > 1
)
```